# Text file split in blocks vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text

I am trying to go through my text file and create a new file that will contain only the text I require. My current line looks like:

```
Car-1I
Colour-39
Cost-328
Dealer-28
 
Car-2
Colour-30
Cost-234
```

For each block of text I would like to read the first line, if the first line ends with an I, then read the next line, if that line contains a colour 39, then I would like to save the whole block of text to another file. If these two conditions aren't met, I dont want to save my values to the new text file.

Before anything about saving my values in classes are mentioned, these blocks of text can vary in size and values, so I dont always have a set range of values which is why i need to skip to the blank line

```
IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\test2.txt", "") 'write to new file
    Dim sKey As String
    Dim sValue As Integer
  
    For Each filterLine As String In File.ReadLines("C:\Users\test.txt")
        sKey = Split(filterLine, ":")(0)
        sValue = Split(filterLine, ":")(1)
        If Not sValue.EndsWith("I") Then


        ElseIf sValue.EndsWith("I") Then

        
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: What's sKey and sValue about?  How is splitting on ":" relevant?  Apart from that seems to me like you've got the logic around about right (Probably could be simplified), so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Do the blocks all follow the pattern Car, Color, Cost, Dealer?

Comment: Looks a great deal like your last question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64135770/skip-block-of-text-from-adding-to-dictionary-vb-net

Comment: Yes, I had some other requirements that I forgot to mention! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
    Dim strFile As String = "c:\Test5\Source.txt"
    Dim strOutFile As String = "c:\Test5\OutPut.txt"
    Dim strOutData As String = ""

    Dim SourceGroups As String() = Split(File.ReadAllText(strFile), vbCrLf + vbCrLf)

    For Each sGroup As String In SourceGroups
        Dim OneGroup() As String = Split(sGroup, vbCrLf)
        If Strings.Right(OneGroup(0), 1) = "I" And (Strings.Right(OneGroup(1), 2) = "39") Then
            If strOutData <> "" Then strOutData += (vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
            strOutData += sGroup
        End If
    Next

    File.WriteAllText(strOutFile, strOutData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method, using [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines) to read lines of text from file. This method doesn't load all the text in memory, it reads from disc single lines of text, so it can also be useful when dealing with big files.

You could loop the `IEnumerable` collection it returns, but also use its [GetEnumerator()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1.getenumerator) method to control more directly when to move to the next line, or move more then one lines forward.
Its [Enumerator.Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1.current) object returns the line of text currently read, [Enumerator.MoveNext()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) moves to the next line.

A [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder) is used to store the strings when a match found. Strings are added to the StringBuilder object using its [AppendLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline) method.
This class is useful when dealing with strings that you need to store, compare and discard (or modify) quickly: since string are immutable, when you use `String` variables directly, especially in loops, you generate a whole lot of garbage that slows down any procedure quite a lot.

The blocks of text stored in the StringBuilder object are then written to a destination file using a [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter) with explicit encoding set to `UTF-8` (writes the BOM). Its methods include asynchronous versions: [`WriteLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.writeline) can be replaced by `await`[`WriteLineAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.writeline) to allow an async procedure.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Dim sourceFilePath = "<Path of the source file>"
Dim resultsFilePath = "<Path of the destination file>"

Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim enumerator = File.ReadLines(sourceFilePath).GetEnumerator()

Using sWriter As New StreamWriter(resultsFilePath, False, Encoding.UTF8)
    While enumerator.MoveNext()
        If enumerator.Current.EndsWith("I") Then
            sb.AppendLine(enumerator.Current)
            enumerator.MoveNext()
            If enumerator.Current.EndsWith("39") Then
                While Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(enumerator.Current)
                    sb.AppendLine(enumerator.Current)
                    enumerator.MoveNext()
                End While
                sWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
            End If
            sb.Clear()
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

Comment: I think the OP only wants the data block if both conditions are met. It seems that Enumerator only moves forward.

Comment: @Mary Yes, both conditions are checked: `If enumerator.Current.EndsWith("I") Then...`, If `enumerator.Current.EndsWith("39") Then ...`. Of course it only moves forward. The StringBuilder begins to store the first validated value, then it keeps going while the conditions are met: *For each block of text I would like to read the first line, if the first line ends with an I, then read the next line, if that line contains a colour 39, then I would like to save the whole block*. Well, there's just another condition. The SB content is saved to a file when a blank line if found and then starts over.

Comment: @Mary If you test it and find that something doesn't add up, you know what you have to do :) Note that this is based on the description. If, for example, the first line that defines a block is not the one that ends with the mentioned `I`, then this code won't work. But it's not hard to fix. You just need to store everything between blank lines and verify later. Then, if also the blank lines are not so blank...

Comment: Yes, but `If enumerator.Current.EndsWith("I") Then` 
        `sb.AppendLine(enumerator.Current)` you write to the string builder when only one condition is met. He only wants to save the data if both Car ends with I and Color ends with 39. I think I already answered his question when he asked it before at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64135770/skip-block-of-text-from-adding-to-dictionary-vb-net

Comment: @Mary Why do you stop reading at the first condition, there's another right after :) The line after, that's where `enumerator.MoveNext()` is moving to.

Comment: I must be missing something obvious. I see `sb.AppendLine` directly after the first condition. He only wants to write the block to the new file if both conditions are met.

Comment: @Mary The first condition is met: store the first line of the block - Move to the next line - Check the second condition on this new line - If the second condition is met, start iterating the next lines until a blank line is found - The StringBuilder inside the loop stores these lines, starting from the one that was validated by the second condition (`enumerator.MoveNext()` is after `sb.AppendLine()`) and keeps going. Did you test it?

Comment: That I get but that is not what he says. 1. read the first line, if the first line ends with an I  2. then read the next line, if that line contains a colour 39  3. then I would like to save the whole block of text to another file.  4. If these two conditions aren't met, I dont want to save my values to the new text file.  Direct quotes from OP question.

Comment: @Mary If the conditions are not met, no lines are saved to a file. The `File.AppendAllText()` call is inside the second `If` block and is executed only after the loop breaks. After that, the StringBuilder is cleared, and is cleared also when the second condition s not met (since it was storing the string added when the first validation passed).

Comment: Finally, I get it. I am just getting too old for this. Very sorry.

Comment: @Mary  Not sure what you are sorry about. Anyway, it's probably more straightforward :) if you build a sample file and debug the code, so you can see when it jumps out of the various blocks.